# Unable to connect to postgres DB via vpn || Able to connect to the postgres server via putty

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to connect to a postgres DB over VPN using Pgadmin. But seeing the error :
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.18.232.207", user "postgres", database "prod1_db", SSL off

172.18.232.207 is the ip allocated to my system by vpn. Reading some community threads I added "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" to the pg_hba.conf file and listen_addresses = '*' to the postgresql.conf and restarted my system but still it did not help and I am still seeing the error. Any suggestion would be of great help to get this through.

Comment: don't `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` ever, at least leave `md5` - if restart did not help (reload enough) you changed wrong `hba.conf`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I double checked the config file and it is the right one. I disconnected my vpn and connected to local postgres instance and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to edit your pg_hba.conf file again and remove the `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` entry! That is very very bad! It allows anyone to connect to any database from any machine using any account with no password. Why on earth would you want to allow that ever?!

You should have an entry like this:

```
host all all 172.18.232.207/32 md5
```

That will allow your machine to connect by password authentication. You should check you always get the same VPN IP address though - most networks will assign an IP from a range for VPN connections. You will have to adjust the CIDR address accordingly.

Comment: Agreed @Lee..but I implemented the all trust line just to see if I am able to connect to the DB at all without any restriction in place. However, that did not work out. Also, I tried the entry that you provided but unfortunately it is still throwing the same error. :(

Comment: Thanks team for the help...I got postgres installed on my unix server >>made the entry for all host but with md5 hash >>reloaded the config>>done!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks team for the help...I got postgres installed on my unix server >>made the entry for all host but with md5 hash >>reloaded the config>>done!! :)